# Uppercase and lowercase substitution with Fn::Sub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a parameterized S3 path (different per environment) that looks something like this example:

```
Environment:
- Name: 'Environment'
  Value: !Ref Environment
- Name: SERVICE_LOGIN_KEYSTORE
  Value: !Sub s3://${Environment}-productsuite-cert/productsuite-pipelinename-${Environment}.jks
```

The issue is that the actual path has the first `${Environment}` in lowercase while the second in uppercase, e.g:

```
s3://qa-productsuite-cert/productsuite-pipelinename-QA.jks
s3://pr-productsuite-cert/productsuite-pipelinename-PR.jks
```

So what I need is something like this:

```
!Sub s3://${Environment:Uppercase}-productsuite-cert/productsuite-pipelinename-${Environment:Lowecase}.jks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using Fn::Transform.

See: 
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions/string_example.yaml

and

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-transform.html

Comment: Thank you! Btw, what is the format, e.g. is it `!Sub s3://${Fn::Transform(Environment, Uppercase)}-productsuite-cert/productsuite-pipelinename-${Fn::Transform(Environment, Lowercase)}.jks`?

Comment: Hello above url yaml code is not working and gives error --> No transform named 871247504605::String found. Rollback requested by user. I have posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609353/aws-cloudformation-how-to-do-string-uppercase-or-lowercase-in-json-yaml-templat

Comment: It's not clear from the README posted, but you need to add that Python file as a transform function rather than just using the upper function. CF doesn't have any built-in support for this and you need to add your own transform function to do it.

Comment: I find this answer a little annoying. Points out the documentation, but the actual syntax/example is still not clear to me.

Comment: Shocking that AWS CloudFormation does not provide this out of the box. You MUST install the "macros" with a separate CF Stack. Then, via AWS Lambda the following example of using this "macro" will work:

`"Fn::Transform": [{"Name": "String","Parameters": {"InputString": {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},"Operation": "Lower"}}]`