# CDK lowercase a string token cross stack reference

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-sagemaker, aws-cdk-typescript

I have a CDK app in which I create a Sagemaker endpoint using `CfnEndpoint`. When I omit the name parameter, CDK generates me a unique one which is great.

```js
const endpoint = new CfnEndpoint(this, "Endpoint", {
  endpointConfigName: endpointConfig.attrEndpointConfigName,
});
```

The problem comes when I want to grant something permissions to invoke the endpoint in *another stack*. I want to grant a lambda function permissions to invoke just that endpoint and not others, so I would usually do something like:

```js
myFunction.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
  effect: Effect.ALLOW,
  actions: ['sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint'],
  resources: [Stack.of(this).formatArn({
    service: 'sagemaker',
    resource: 'endpoint',
    resourceName: endpoint.attrEndpointName, // <- reference the endpoint name from another stack
  })],
}));
```

The problem is that when I do this, the arn resolves with a mixed case endpoint name:

`arn:aws:sagemaker:ap-southeast-2:012345678910:endpoint/Endpoint3015B993-FcX1jFxPQKeE`

And my lambda is not granted the appropriate permissions, as the name needs to be completely lowercase to do this.

I've also tried using the `Fn::Transform` CloudFormation macro like so:

```js
myFunction.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
  effect: Effect.ALLOW,
  actions: ['sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint'],
  resources: [Stack.of(this).formatArn({
    service: 'sagemaker',
    resource: 'endpoint',
    resourceName: Fn.transform('String', {
      Operation: "Lower",
      InputString: endpoint.attrEndpointName,
    }),
  })],
}));
```

But this throws an error when I attempt to deploy:

```
Error: Failed to create ChangeSet cdk-deploy-change-set on MyStack: FAILED, The value of parameter InputString under transform String must resolve to a string, number, boolean or a list of any of these.
```

It sounds like that transform only works on static values or cloudformation inputs.

Does anyone know a way I can construct an arn with a lowercase endpoint name?

I don't really want to hardcode a name for my endpoint, and a custom resource lambda feels like overkill, but I suppose either of those would sort it.

Comment: I wonder if `Endpoint.grantInvoke` actually works: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/ae455d822c9da2e4a1b23c548e9d220d8e95a346/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-sagemaker-alpha/lib/endpoint.ts#L298

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that works, but feels overkill with a lambda function:

```js
const endpointArnCustomResource = new CustomResource(this, "EndpointArnCustomResource", {
  properties: {
    endpointArn: Stack.of(this).formatArn({
      service: "sagemaker",
      resource: "endpoint",
      resourceName: endpoint.attrEndpointName,
    }),
  },
  serviceToken: new Provider(this, "EndpointArnProvider", {
    onEventHandler: new Function(this, "EndpointArnFunction", {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      handler: "index.handler",
      code: Code.fromInline(`exports.handler = async (event) => {
        return {
          PhysicalResourceId: event.PhysicalResourceId,
          Data: {
            endpointArn: event.ResourceProperties.endpointArn.toLowerCase(),
          },
        };
      }`)
    }),
  }).serviceToken,
});

// This has the endpoint arn in lowercase
const endpointArn = endpointArnCustomResource.getAttString("endpointArn");
```

Comment: I too ended up using a custom resource and a lambda. According to this offhand github issue comment, deploy-time values cannot be lowercased through other means: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18802#issuecomment-1028414189